# How do you get the world position from the screen position in a URP shader graph used in a ScriptableRenderPass?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I'm using a shader graph in the Universal Shader Pipeline (URP) to do some post-processing in a ScriptableRenderPass. How do I get the world coordinates of the screen position?

I have tried using the View Direction node, set to World:
[image]

And I have tried the Screen Position node, with either a Transform node or Transformation Matrix node:
[image]

Neither seems to be working because the colors change as I move the camera around, but I would expect the color to stay the same since the world position of the GameObject in the view is not changing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it in the past:

[image: Shader graph]

Comment: In URP? In Unity 2019?

Comment: I should have specified the Unity version above. I gave up because it seemed to be a bug in the Screen Position or View Direction node.

Comment: Can't recall which URP version I originally made this graph for, as it was from an older answer. Did you encounter any specific problems using this example in your version?

Comment: Its been a while since I looked at it (the question is from Aug '20), and I gave up trying to get it to work. I was trying to do underwater fog, and there is probably a better way than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are after from your description, but this appears to do it:

[image: screen to world transform node]

Here is a project demonstrating a colour effect that stays on the horizon as the camera rotates: https://github.com/paulsinnett/PostProcessFullScreenURP